# Java: How to handle multiple Hibernate transactions in one request?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I'm not sure where to open my `Transaction` object. Inside the service layer? Or the controller layer?

My `Controller` basically has two services, let's call them `AService` and `BService`. Then my code goes something like:

```
public class Controller {
    public AService aService = new AService();
    public BService bService = new BService();

    public void doSomething(SomeData data) {
        //Transaction transaction = HibernateUtil.getSession().openTransaction();
        if (data.getSomeCondition()) {
            aService.save(data.getSomeVar1());
            bService.save(data.getSomeVar2());
        }
        else {
            bService.save(data.getSomeVar2());
        }


        //transaction.commit(); or optional try-catch with rollback 
    }
}
```

The behavior I want is that if `bService#save` fails, then I could invoke a `transaction#rollback` so that whatever was saved in `aService` would be rolled back as well. This only seems possible if I create one single transaction for both saves.

But looking at it in a different perspective, it looks really ugly that my `Controller` is dependent on the `Transaction`. It would be better if I create the `Transaction` inside the respective services, (something like how Spring @Transactional works), but if I do it that way, then I don't know how to achieve what I want to happen...

EDIT: Fixed code, added another condition. I am not using any Spring dependencies so the usage of @Transactional is out of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're asking with another layer of abstraction and using composition.

```
public class CompositeABService {
  @Autowired
  private AService aservice;
  @Autowired
  private BService bservice;

  @Transactional
  public void save(Object value1, Object value2) {
    aservice.save( value1 );
    bservice.save( value2 );
  }
}

public class AService {
  @Transactional
  public void save(Object value) {
    // joins an existing transaction if one exists, creates a new one otherwise.
  }
}

public class BService {
  @Transactional
  public void save(Object value) {
    // joins an existing transaction if one exists, creates a new one otherwise.
  }
}
```

This same pattern is typically used when you need to interact with multiple repositories as a part of a single unit of work (e.g. transaction).

Now all your controller needs to depend upon is `CompositeABService` or whatever you wish to name it.

Comment: Okay - might be slightly off topic but I am not using any Spring dependencies so I'm just manually creating new transactions. If I open a Transaction in CompositeABService.save() - this means that opening another Transaction inside AService.save() and BService.save() would cause an error. Please take a look at my edit